# SQL Error in stacked WHERE statements using WHERE NOT EXISTS

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-clause

I'm having a reoccurring error in my SQL statement, and I cannot figure out how to fix it.
The `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"` is not very helpful as well.

This is the code snippet in question:

```
INSERT INTO example.table (first, second, third, fourth, fifth) 
(SELECT first,second,third,fourth,'constant' 
 FROM example.table 
 WHERE some_id=42)
 WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (SELECT 1 
  FROM example.table 
  WHERE (first,third,status)=(SELECT first,third,'request'     FROM example.table 
  WHERE some_id=42));
```

Everything works as intended up until the 'WHERE NOT EXISTS', but everything also works if I replace the second line with just values instead of searching them from the table.
How can I fix this code?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: what flavor of sql?

Comment: It's PostgreSQL

Comment: What you want to do? INSERT ... WHERE

Comment: You have two WHERE clauses in your main SELECT statement. Change the “WHERE NOT EXISTS” to AND. Your parentheses seem to indicate that the second WHERE refers to the INSERT not the SELECT; that’s not valid syntax, everything from SELECT onwards is part of the SELECT statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps

```
INSERT INTO example.table (first, second, third, fourth, fifth) 
SELECT first,second,third,fourth,'constant' 
FROM example.table 
WHERE some_id=42
 and NOT EXISTS
   (SELECT 1 FROM example.table 
    WHERE (first,third,status)=
       (SELECT first,third,'request' FROM example.table WHERE some_id=42));
```

Answer (score 1):

There can only be one `WHERE` clause per DML command, as the syntax error indicates.

But I am also pretty sure you don't want to introduce a 4th (uncorrelated!) instance of `example.table` in the `EXISTS` subquery.  That would exclude rows based on *any* row with `some_id=42`, while you most certainly want to just base that on the row at hand.

So refer back to the instance you are selecting from.

```sql
INSERT INTO example.table t1
      (first, second, third, fourth, fifth) 
SELECT first, second, third, fourth, 'constant' 
FROM   example.table t2
WHERE  t2.some_id = 42
AND    NOT EXISTS (
   SELECT FROM example.table t3
   WHERE (t3.first, t3.third, t3.status)
       = (t2.first, t2.third,'request')
   );
```

Related:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)